# Unable to wrap a SAPUI5 application using cordova 3.4.0

Tags: android, cordova, sapui5

I am trying to wrap a SAPUI5 SplitApp application using cordova 3.4.0 and run it from an android device.

Initially, it gave a resources folder error, but have managed to resolve that too.

Now ,there is a new error that has cropped up. The error screenshot is attached here.

Error Uncaught ReferencError: sap is not defined at file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js

Regards,
Aaron D’C

Comment: Where is the screenshot ?

Answer (score 0):

I think sap ui libraries are not properly loaded. 
Please check whether the resources properly configured in index.html or not. Check **src** entry in the following script tag

```
<script id='sap-ui-bootstrap'
        src='resources/sap-ui-core.js'
        data-sap-ui-theme='sap_bluecrystal'
        data-sap-ui-libs='sap.ui.commons'></script>
```